# Whats wrong with this Coredata code? its crashing. Error : Illegal attempt to establish a relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

**Code:**

```
self.attachment?.maintenanceRequest = self.maintenanceRequest
self.attachment?.property = self.attachment?.maintenanceRequest?.property
self.attachment?.imageDescription = descriptionNote
maintenanceRequest?.managedObjectContext?.saveRecursively()
```

**RelationShips:**

maintenanceRequest -> attachment  RelationShip: 1 to many

attachment ->  property           RelationShip: 1 to 1

maintenanceRequest -> property    RelationShip: 1 to 1

**Crash Stack:**
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'maintenanceRequest' between objects in different contexts (source = <MaintenanceAttachment: 0x286992170> (entity: MaintenanceAttachment; id: 0x82c1d7be038b48e9 <x-coredata://6BC7C143-D989-4AA9-87C4-72CF55B15121/MaintenanceAttachment/p298>; data: { createdOn = 1692375851; fileAssociationId = 0; fileName = "169237585178099.jpg"; hasNativeUpdates = 1; imageDescription = nil; imageLatitude = 0; imageLongitude = 0; insepctionProblem = nil; isAddingNew = nil; isAttachmentDeleted = 0; isAttachmentVisibleToResident = 1; isEdited = nil; maintenanceRequest = nil; modificationDate = nil; property = nil; url = nil; user = "0x82c1d7be26eb4979 <x-coredata://6BC7C143-D989-4AA9-87C4-72CF55B15121/User/p1>"; }) , destination = <EntrataFacilities.MaintenanceRequest: 0x286e914a0> (entity: MaintenanceRequest; id: 0x82c1d7bb74ab49f9 <x-coredata://6BC7C143-D989-4AA9-87C4-72CF55B15121/MaintenanceRequest/p10899>; data: <fault>))

I am thinking instead of saving **maintenanceRequest managedObjectContext**, i have to save **attachment's managedObjectContext**

Comment: The crash tells you what you are doing wrong; you are trying to create a relationship between objects in different contexts. All of your objects should be in the same managed object context.

Comment: please format the printout as code ... that will make  it look as it should